# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [chartDataProviderName is not valid] Callback failed: MyController/ACTION$getChartData

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, aura

Hi I am getting the following error.

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [chartDataProviderName is not valid]
>   Callback failed: apex://MyController/ACTION$getChartData

**.cmp file**

```
<aura:component controller="MyController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.MyResources + '/MyResources/styles/styles.min.css'}" />
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
                           $Resource.MyResources + '/MyResources/scripts/test.min.js',
                           $Resource.MyResources + '/MyResources/scripts/test1.min.js'
                           )}" 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setup}" />

    <aura:attribute name="chartName" default="BarChart" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="chartDataProviderName" default="BarChartDataProvider" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="rendertodiv" default="rendertodiv" type="String" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <div id="{!v.rendertodiv}"></div>
</aura:component>
```

**ComponentController.js**

```
({
    setup : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.createChart(component)
    },
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.rendertodiv", "rendertodiv-" + helper.generateUniqueId());
    }
})
```

**ComponentHelper.js**

```
({
    createChart : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getChartData");
        action.setParams({"dataProviderName":component.get("v.chartDataProviderName")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            debugger
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                if (result.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
                    component.set("v.data", result.data);
                }
                else {
                    component.set("v.data", []);
                }
                if (result.hasOwnProperty('props')){
                    component.set("v.props", result.props);
                }
                else {
                    component.set("v.props", []);
                }
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR"){
                throw new Error("chartDataProviderName is not valid");
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    generateUniqueId : function(){
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        })
    }
})
```

**apex Class(Controller)**

```
global with sharing class MyController {
    @AuraEnabled
    global static string getChartData(string dataProviderName){
        iChartDataProvider dp;
        dp = (iChartDataProvider)type.forName(dataProviderName).newInstance();
        return dp.getChartData();
    }
}
```

**BarChartDataProvider (Apex Class)**

```
global with sharing class BarChartDataProvider implements iChartDataProvider {
    global String getChartData(){
        string data = '[{"StageName":"Prospecting","Amount":"224690"},{"StageName":"Qualification","Amount":"145008"},{"StageName":"Needs Analysis","Amount":"348000"},{"StageName":"Value Proposition","Amount":"422290"},{"StageName":"Id. Decision Makers","Amount":"584035"},{"StageName":"Perception Analysis","Amount":"194503"},{"StageName":"Proposal/Price Quote","Amount":"270289"},{"StageName":"Negotiation/Review","Amount":"202056"},{"StageName":"Closed Won","Amount":"364300"},{"StageName":"Closed Lost","Amount":"234450"}]';
        string props = '[]';
        string datum = '{"data":'+data+',"props":'+props+'}';
        return datum;
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
global interface iChartDataProvider {
    string getChartData();
}
```

Comment: Message comes from your client side controller where you throw an exception. Something is wrong with your server side method. You're assuming that type.forName should work, gotta add some error handling there.

Comment: @Raul I am not getting y state is "ERROR"

Comment: Instead `throw new Error("chartDataProviderName is not valid");` which is a generic message, you need to handle it properly for getting the right message. Reference to documentation: [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Comment: you can use debug log on server side to find why exception is coming?